# WCF/ASP.net wen services Profilers to monitor request received, responses sent, time taken to process request, memory consumption etc...?

Tags: wcf

Could you all suggest me a Profiler for WCF/ASP.net wen services Profilers to monitor request received, responses sent, time taken to process request, memory consumption etc...?

Thanks,
Srinivas PV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has an **extensive** set of performance counters built in:

- [WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx)
- [Using WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750527.aspx)

Just use these and fire up perfmon.exe - no special profiler needed, really...